# WordPress Plugins not Showing in Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Using the Latest version of WordPress, I have a site I'm maintaining for a client that someone else built using WooThemes. It's running on a Windows Server.

When going to the plugins menu, the only plugins that show up are Akismet, and Contact Form 7. I've installed other plugins since such as ShareThis, but none of them show up. If I click on 'Active (15)' menu item at the top, I still only see the 2 plugins.

It's not part of a multi-site. I've checked permissions (windows), I've checked the folder structure. Everything looks fine as much as I can tell.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends on the plugin, because no all plugins use the menu bar, but generally when a plugin is activated is under the Settings menu and if your client or you have a [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) (permission) like an Author you cannot see any many menu options as an admin.